# ClickHouse deduplication/upsert with different functions per column

Tags: duplicates, clickhouse, upsert

I have a ClickHouse table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id Int,
    property_id Int,
    created_at DateTime('UTC'),
    modified_at DateTime('UTC'),
    data Int,
    json_str Nullable(String)
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_at)
ORDER BY (property_id, created_at);
```

When inserting new rows, I want to update (upsert) existing rows with matching `id` and `property_id` according to these rules:

- `created_at`: Keep the earliest
- `modified_at`: Keep the latest
- `data`: Keep the value of the row with the latest `modified_at`
- `json_str`: Ideally, deep merge json objects (stored as strings) of all matching rows

I did quite a bit of research and tried setting up a deduplication pipeline, using a source table, a destination table (`ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree`) and a materialized view (using `minState`, `maxState`, `argMaxState`) but I couldn't figure it out so far. I'm running into errors related to primary key, partitioning, wrong aggregation functions, etc. Even a setup without merging `json_str` would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, I found a solution (ignoring `json_str` for now):

```sql
-- Source table with duplicates
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingest;
CREATE TABLE ingest
(
    id Int,
    property_id Int,
    created_at DateTime('UTC'),  -- Should be preserved
    modified_at DateTime('UTC'), -- Should be updated
    data Int                     -- Should be updated
) ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (property_id, created_at);

-- Destination table without duplicates
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dedup;
CREATE TABLE dedup
(
    id Int,
    property_id Int,
    created_at_state AggregateFunction(min, DateTime),
    modified_at_state AggregateFunction(max, DateTime),
    data_state AggregateFunction(argMax, Int, DateTime)
) ENGINE = SummingMergeTree
ORDER BY (property_id, id);

-- Transformation pipeline
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS pipeline;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW pipeline TO dedup
AS SELECT
       id,
       property_id,
       minState(created_at) AS created_at_state,
       maxState(modified_at) AS modified_at_state,
       argMaxState(data, modified_at) AS data_state
FROM ingest
GROUP BY property_id, id;

-- Insert data with a duplicate
INSERT INTO ingest (id, property_id, created_at, modified_at, data)
VALUES (1, 100, '2022-01-01 08:00:00', '2022-01-01 08:00:00', 2000),
       (1, 100, '2022-01-01 08:01:00', '2022-01-01 08:01:00', 3000),
       (2, 100, '2022-01-01 08:00:00', '2022-01-01 08:00:00', 4000),
       (3, 200, '2022-01-01 08:05:00', '2022-01-01 08:05:00', 5000);

-- Query deduplicated table with merge functions
SELECT id,
       property_id,
       toDateTime(minMerge(created_at_state), 'UTC') AS created_at,
       toDateTime(maxMerge(modified_at_state), 'UTC') AS modified_at,
       argMaxMerge(data_state) AS data
FROM dedup
GROUP BY property_id, id
ORDER BY id, property_id;
```

| id | property_id | created_at | modified_at | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-01-01T08:00Z | 2022-01-01T08:01Z | 3000 |
| 2 | 100 | 2022-01-01T08:00Z | 2022-01-01T08:00Z | 4000 |
| 3 | 200 | 2022-01-01T08:05Z | 2022-01-01T08:05Z | 5000 |